# RecyclerView horizontal LinearLayoutManager with multiple rows

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-recyclerview

I want to make a Layout Manager that will represent its items in a Tag-Cloud way of representation, just as on the Image below.

[image]

There are libraries that do this but I just want to learn how to do it by using the RecyclerView and its LayoutManager pattern. StaggeredGridLayoutManager is out of option because you must specify the number of columns just as for a GridLayoutManager, and what I need in this particular case is make some rows contain 2 items, some 1 and some 3 or more elements. I was thinking of using a LinearLayoutManager with a Horizontal Orientation but instead of making it scrollable horizontaly, I'd need to make it break the elements for which there is no more space in the current row - positioned in a new row. But I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone at least guide me into the basics of the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use this link https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Comment: thanks but this is not for a RecyclerView implementation.

Comment: Is the amount of vertical rows a fixed size?

Comment: Nope, it depends on the number of elements to show and their size(s).

Comment: The image you have shown can be done perfectly using FlowLayout as mentioned by @Joker. If you need some specific functionality that only recyclerview can provide then please state that. If not then FlowLayout is the correct answer

Comment: Try this https://github.com/greenfrvr/hashtag-view